# How to create dynamically and automatically a user at login if it does not exist?

Tags: users, login

Is it possible to create dynamically a user at login if it does not exist, and register the password (s)he typed to log-in ?
...And execute a script before the DM launches to setup the home ?

(I mean without re-writing from scratch a login manager...)

Comment: Login at console, in the DM login screen (which DM?), remote over `ssh` or what? Btw, I wouldn't want a machine to create a new user on each typo in my user name.

Comment: More likely a graphical DM, but I'd like it to work on any login type. The use-case would be to have a better than anonymous system, with home directory on ramfs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PAM plugin and tell Linux that it can ask that for user authentication.

Alternatively, you could also tell Linux to use LDAP for authentication, and implement an LDAP server that just "OKs" every login attempt.